# How can I run a custom task (different from test or build) from a keychord shortcut in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I can assign a keychord to 2 standard tasks: `build` and `test` in VSCode. I need to do the same with a custom task. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

Use **`runTask`** with `args`.

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "The name of your task"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently. 
[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6550) is the github issue with the feature request. Looks like it keeps getting pushed to 'the next' release.

Answer (score 1):

As [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41512460/2392157) says, you currently cannot. But until it is fixed, there is a ...

#### Workaround using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org):

Run fixed command line using keyboard shortcut:

```
^!1::Run mytask.exe myfile.txt
```

The above one launches command line `mytask.exe myfile.txt` on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

If you want to limit scope of the shortcut from global to VSCode only, add [#IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) directive before that line.

Of course, you can also expand the macro to determine the file dynamically (or from user input) but I wanted to show you some minimum example which is a way to go.