# How to run a script on the current file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In TextMate, you can run a shell script on your file or a selection and either replace the selection with the output or insert the output after.

How can you do that easily in VS Code?

By easily, I would like to be able to launch some script with a keyboard shortcut, with a same shortcut being associated to different commands depending on the language. For example, having all linters under the same shortcut (it was just an example, I know you can make them run on save).

I think it is possible to do it on existing files (some extensions do it), but what about unsaved buffers?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this extension?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.edit-with-shell

Comment: Can you bind a shortcut to a specific shell script? (I edited the question in this direction)

Comment: Yes, make it into a task and then use the command "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask", to bind it and run it.  See the last  answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510632/how-can-i-run-a-custom-task-different-from-test-or-build-from-a-keychord-in-vs/44981800#44981800

Comment: @Mark yes, but 1. the tasks are only for one project 2. I don't want to configure a task for each file

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually ask for solution to multiple problems.

1. run a shell script on your file
2. run a shell script on a selection and replace the selection with the output
3. run a shell script on a selection and insert the output after

You can use [Command Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edonet.vscode-command-runner) extension to solve the first problem (for some advanced use cases, you might encounter some problems).

```
{
    "command-runner.terminal.name": "runCommand",
    "command-runner.terminal.autoClear": true,
    "command-runner.terminal.autoFocus": true,
    "command-runner.commands": {
        "echo workspaceFolder": "echo ${workspaceFolder}",
        "echo file": "echo ${file}"
    }
}
```

To solve the second problem i use [Filter Text](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yhirose.FilterText) extension. For example you can use:

```
"filterText.commandList": [
    {
        "name": "Sort unique",
        "description": "Sorts and find the unique entries",
        "command": "sort | uniq"
    },
    {
        "name": "Columnize CSV",
        "description": "Columnize comma separated values",
        "command": "column -s \",\" -t"
    },
    {
        "name": "XML lint",
        "description": "Run the command through xmllint",
        "command": "xmllint --format -"
    }
]
```

To solve the third problem, you can use [Filter Text](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yhirose.FilterText) extension but have to modify the command. For example:

```
$ echo HELLO | tee >(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
HELLO
hello
```

or, you can do something like:

```
$ echo "HELLO" | { read test; echo $test; } | tee >(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
HELLO
hello
```

So, it first prints the input, then the output.